# Select query with where clause including null not giving desired output

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using very basic query as follows:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE COL1='VALUE' AND COL2 IS NULL;
```

The above query is not selecting the id with null `col2` value. But when i use following query:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE COL2 IS NULL;
```

It gives me the `id` i want. But  am not able to figure out why is it not working with col1 clause in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because COL1 is different from 'VALUE'? Because, what you said *works*:

```
SQL> with test (id, col1, col2) as
  2  (select 100, 'A', null from dual)
  3  select id
  4  from test
  5  where col1 = 'A'
  6    and col2 is null;

        ID
----------
       100

SQL>
```

Now, your turn - prove me wrong (i.e. provide your own example).

Comment: I know it should work and that is why i am not sure as to why it is not working. There is one record in my table which is not coming with the clause i stated above. I was hoping for a suggestion to try.

Comment: Unless you provide an example, it is difficult to guess what is wrong or what you did wrong. So - go ahead, follow what I've done, post contents of your table, query you used and the way Oracle responded - just edit your initial message to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Found the issue. Query was fine. The cell was actually not null and that is why it was not getting selected. It had a dot. killed a lot of time.

Comment: Oh well. Things like that happen. I'm glad you found the culprit!